# Minimum of polynomial interpolation

Tags: polynomials, optimization, interpolation

We seek a polynomial of rank $2$ that interpolates the function $f(x)=x^3$ in the interval $[-1,1]$ at the points $x=-1,x=0,x=a$ were $0<a<1$. We need find the number $a$ that make the approximation optimal by minimizing the integral
$$
\int_{-1}^{1} \left(x^3-p_2(x) \right)^2\ dx.
$$

So if I find the Lagrange polynomial for the points $(-1,-1),(0,0),(a,a^3)$, I get:
$$
P_L(a) =-1+(x+1)+(a-1)(x+1)x=ax^2+ax-x^2.
$$
But I don't know what make now, probably take derivatives of the integral to find its minimum...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The full answer is (continue was Claude Leibovici wrote). We make integral of it and we get:

$2\int\limits_{0}^{1} [a^2x^2 +(a^2-4a+1)x^4] \ dx=\frac{2}{3}a^2+\frac{2}{5}(a^2-4a+1)=g(a)$ 
Now we need obtain such $a$ that our integral get it minimum, so we need take first derivative on $g(a)$ and make it equal to zero:
$g'(a)=0=\frac{2a}{3}+\frac{2a}{5}-\frac{4}{5}$
And the solution is: 
**$a=3/4$**

Answer (score 1):

By hand, it is quite simple because of the symmetry
$$ \left(x^3-p_2(x) \right)^2=a^2 x^2+2 (a-1) a x^3+(a^2-4a+1) x^4+2(1- a) x^5$$ and we do not care about the odd powers.

So, you just need to integrate between the bounds and because of the symmetry
$$\int_{-1}^{1} \left(x^3-p_2(x) \right)^2\, dx=2\int_{0}^{1} \Big[a^2 x^2+ (a^2-4a+1) x^4\Big]\,dx$$

Answer (score 0):

Now that you have $p_a(x)$, you can explicitly compute the error function
$$
E(a) = \int_{-1}^1 \left(x^3 - p_a(x)\right)^2dx
$$
and then minimize $E(a)$.

You should get $E(a)$ to be a nice quadratic so the minimization is straight-forward even without derivatives... You can check your work with [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5B+%28x%5E3-a*x%5E2%2Ba*x-x%5E2%29%5E2%2C+%7Bx%2C-1%2C1%7D%5D).

Comment: I need to solve it by hand, without computer

Comment: @DavidShulman you shouldn't need a compute to minimize a quadratic.